# What moves can Toxapex learn?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I have a Toxapex but it is weak af,

Peck,
Poison Sting,
Bite,
Baneful Bunker,

Please tell me what moves they can learn and what level

Thanks!

Comment: It'd be faster to search the internet than to ask here.

Comment: Toxapex is primarily a defensive pokemon; it is built to slowly whittle down opponents' health through effects like poison.

Comment: https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Toxapex_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#Learnset. No, I'm not copy-pasting it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Any question like this can be answered by looking at the [bulbapedia page](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Toxapex_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#By_leveling_up) of any given Pokémon.

According to the page for Toxapex, these are the moves it can learn and at what level:

> **Moves not possible in-game**
>
> lvl.1  Baneful Bunker
>
> lvl.1  Poison Sting
>
> lvl.1  Peck
>
> lvl.1  Bite
>
> lvl.1  Toxic Spikes
>
> lvl.5  Peck
>
> lvl.9  Bite
>
> lvl.13 Toxic Spikes
>
> lvl.17 Wide Guard
>
> lvl.21 Toxic
>
> lvl.25 Venoshock
>
> lvl.29 Spike Cannon
>
> lvl.33 Recover
>
> lvl.37 Poison Jab
>
> **Upon Evolution**
>
> lvl.38  Baneful Bunker
>
> **By Leveling Up**
>
> lvl.44 Venom Drench
>
> lvl.51 Pin Missile
>
> lvl.58 Liquidation

Toxipex can learn TMs, but these are the moves it can learn by level.